# Setting Default value for column in MS access using sql query in Python

Tags: python, ms-access, default, pypyodbc

I am using pypyodbc(python 64bit)  to connect to MS access(64 bit) for my project. Using SQL query ( such SET DEFAULT, DEFAULT=0) i have to set column to the default values. But query results in string error. I donot want to use OLE DB. Is there any  way to fix this?

Comment: That query doesn't look valid at all. Please share your actual code.

Comment: Access' SQL dialect does support that `SET` command.

Comment: I have tried following queries 
"CREATE TABLE SectionChange(SecID integer SET DEFAULT=10, StartTime varchar(50), EndTime varchar(50), indes varchar(50))"

and
"CREATE TABLE SectionChange(SecID integer SET DEFAULT 10, StartTime varchar(50), EndTime varchar(50), indes varchar(50))"

Why it is so only for ODBC connection?. I have heard that SET DEFAULT command works for OLE DB or ADO connection. How do i fix this without going to OLE DB or ADO connection. Please help.

Comment: Try changing `SecID integer SET DEFAULT=10` to `SecID integer DEFAULT 10`

Comment: I tried SecID integer DEFAULT 10. Still the same error. I have tried SecID integer DEFAULT '10' . None of the syntax type seems to be working

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that DEFAULT is only supported under OLEDB. My apologies for the false lead.